# Getting incorrect index when using redis-cli -pipe to read a csv file

Tags: csv, awk, redis, redis-cli

I am using this [tutorial](http://blog.mostafazh.me/2015/07/21/fastest-way-to-import-big-csv-to-redis/) to read a CSV file using redis-cli -pipe.

The structure of my csv file is:

```
0,  col1  ,   col2  ,  col3  ,.......,  col20  
1,11222323, random- , ----ww ,......., text    

and so on
```

Now, I am running this command:

`awk -F, 'NR > 1{ print "SET", "\"Number_"$1"\"", "\""$0"\"" }' redis_csv_number_file_2.csv | src/redis-cli --pipe`

Found that that this command isn't working at all. Any reasons why it wouldn't work?

Comment: do you have pipe "|" or comma"," in  your input csv ? if pipe use "awk -F\|"

Comment: @Chet It is comma only.

Comment: Please can you edit the same in question and add few lines from your csv?

Comment: @Chet Found that redis is taking `Integer_Col2' values as keys too, while I want it all to be from the first column and it is an anomaly.

Comment: @Chet Updated the question.